# Using mex to compile an .cpp file to a .m file

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, compilation, mex

I'm using Matlab R2017b on Windows 10.

When I'm using [Curvelab-2.1.3](https://github.com/benkary/matlabCode/tree/master/CurveLab-2.1.3), I found that I need an important function called `fdct_wrapping_mex` in `/fdct_wrapping_cpp/src/`. I don't have the relevant `.m` file.

I tried to compile it using `mex fdct_wrapping_mex.cpp`. I get this error.

```
C:\Users\liziyang\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_17263405357879_2632\fdct_wrapping_mex.obj:fdct_wrapping_mex.cpp:(.text+0x337):undefined reference to`fdct_wrapping_ns::fdct_wrapping(int, int, int, int, int,fdct_wrapping_ns::NumMat<std::complex<double> >&,std::vector<std::vector<fdct_wrapping_ns::NumMat<std::complex<double> >,std::allocator<fdct_wrapping_ns::NumMat<std::complex<double> > > >,std::allocator<std::vector<fdct_wrapping_ns::NumMat<std::complex<double> >,std::allocator<fdct_wrapping_ns::NumMat<std::complex<double> > > > > >&)'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also have Matlab R2010a, but I not a fitting compiler.

**Question**

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library so can't help much, but I noticed: 1) the library appears to provide both Matlab and C++ implementations, so maybe you can use the Matlab-only version, which does not require mex; 2) The PDF gives compilation instructions for the C++ code using `make`. `make` is one of the approaches used to compile libraries that are too large and complex to compile using a simple `mex` command. However they only test it for Unix so it might require significant changes to get it working on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me these important information.I've just found the file int matlab-only version, but have not found it.I tried to use `make` in Windows Matlab but failed. I'm looking for other ways to solve it now.